# Problem with toggle animations on accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, logic

I'm trying to work on a accordion with a toggle (plus when closed and minus when opened), However, when I click on an accordion that is open to another one that is closed, the toggle of the newly closed accordion does not change to +, keeping -

Follow my code:

**HTML**

```
<section id="duvidas-frequentes">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 titulo-duvidas-frequentes">
                <h2><?php the_field('titulo_secao_duvidas'); ?></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 caixa-duvidas">
                <div class="accordion" id="accordionDuvidas">
                    <?php if(have_rows('duvidas') ):
                        while( have_rows('duvidas') ) : the_row(); ?>
                            <div class="duvidas-individual">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-header" id="<?php echo "accordion-".get_row_index(); ?>">
                                        <span id="animation" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?php echo "dropdown-".get_row_index(); ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="<?php echo "dropdown-".get_row_index(); ?>">
                                            <div class="wrap">
                                                <div class="toggle open"></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <h2 class="mb-0">
                                                <button class="btn btn-link btn-block text-left" type="button">
                                                    <?php the_sub_field('titulo_duvida'); ?>
                                                </button>
                                            </h2>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="<?php echo "dropdown-".get_row_index(); ?>" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="<?php echo "accordion-".get_row_index(); ?>" data-parent="#accordionDuvidas">
                                        <div class="card-body">
                                            <?php the_sub_field('resposta_duvida'); ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

**CSS**

```
#duvidas-frequentes .titulo-duvidas-frequentes h2{
            font-size: 42px;
            font-weight: 700;
            line-height: 43px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #duvidas-frequentes .caixa-duvidas{
            max-width: 780px;
            margin: auto;
        }
        #duvidas-frequentes .accordion .card-header{
            padding-top: 8px;
            padding-bottom: 8px;
            transition: background .5s;
            background: #FFF;
        }
        #duvidas-frequentes #animation{
            position: relative;
        }
        #duvidas-frequentes .accordion h2{
            padding: 0;
        }
        #duvidas-frequentes .accordion h2 button{
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 22px;
            font-weight: 500;
            font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
            line-height: 30px;
            color: #000;
            text-decoration: none;
            max-width: 700px;
            padding-left: 40px;
        }
        #duvidas-frequentes .accordion .card{
            border: 1px solid #948075;
        }
        #duvidas-frequentes .accordion .collapse, #duvidas-frequentes .accordion .collapsing, #duvidas-frequentes .accordion .collapse.show{
            border-top: 1px solid #948075;
        }
        #duvidas-frequentes .accordion .collapse .card-body, #duvidas-frequentes .collapsing .card-body{
            padding: 8px 20px;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: 300;
            font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
            line-height: 25px;
        }
        .wrap {
            width: 28px;
            height: 28px;
            background: transparent;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            cursor: pointer;
            left: 0;
            top: calc(50% - 10px);
            position: absolute;
        }
        .toggle {
            border-radius: 5px;
            width: 25px;
            height: 5px;
            background: #FFF;
            position: relative;
            transition: 0.25s all cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.67, 0.09, 0.97);
        }
        .toggle.open::after {
            transform: rotate(90deg);
            opacity: 1;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        .toggle.open {
            transform: rotate(90deg);
            background: #948075;
        }
        .toggle::after {
            content: "";
            width: 25px;
            transition: 0.25s all cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.67, 0.09, 0.97);
            transition-delay: 0.1s;
            height: 5px;
            position: absolute;
            opacity: 0;
            background: #948075;
        }
        #duvidas-frequentes .accordion .card-header.active{
            background: #948075;
        }
```

**JQuery**

```
            $("#duvidas-frequentes .accordion .card-header:first").addClass('active');
            $("#duvidas-frequentes .accordion .collapse:first").addClass('show');
            $("#duvidas-frequentes .accordion .card-header.active #animation .wrap .toggle").removeClass("open");

            $("#duvidas-frequentes .accordion .card-header #animation").click(function(){

                $("duvidas-frequentes .accordion .card-header #animation .wrap .toggle").addClass("open");
                $("#duvidas-frequentes .accordion .card-header").removeClass("active");

                if($(this).parent('.card-header').siblings('.collapse').hasClass('show')){
                    $(this).find(".toggle").addClass("open");
                }else{
                    $(this).parent(".card-header").addClass('active');
                    $(this).find(".toggle").removeClass('open');
                }
                if(!$("duvidas-frequentes .accordion .card-header #animation .wrap .toggle").hasClass('open')){
                    $("duvidas-frequentes .accordion .card-header #animation .wrap .toggle").addClass('open');
                }
            });
```

I already try a lot of situations but I'm stucked now :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of toggle animations on an accordion using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript:

**HTML**

```
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-section">
    <button class="accordion-toggle">Section 1</button>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      <p>Content of section 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-section">
    <button class="accordion-toggle">Section 2</button>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      <p>Content of section 2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-section">
    <button class="accordion-toggle">Section 3</button>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      <p>Content of section 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.accordion {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.accordion-section {
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height 0.3s;
}

.accordion-toggle {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.accordion-toggle:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.accordion-toggle.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.accordion-content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  height: 0;
  background-color: white;
  transition: height 0.3s;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
const accordionToggles = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-toggle");

accordionToggles.forEach(toggle => {
  toggle.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    const content = this.nextElementSibling;
    content.style.height = content.style.height ? "" : content.scrollHeight + "px";
  });
});
```

This code creates an accordion with three sections. When a section is clicked, the JavaScript code toggles the "active" class on the toggle button, and adjusts the height of the associated content section. The CSS styles provide the visual effects for expanding and collapsing the sections.